# If $\int_a ^b g^2 = 0$, then $\int_a ^b fg = 0$ (edit: without Cauchy-Schwarz)

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, solution-verification, riemann-integration

I'm trying to prove that if $f$ and $g$ (real numbers only) are each integrable on $[a,b]$, and $\int_a ^b g^2 = 0$, then $\int_a ^b fg = 0$.

**Edit:** Here, I'm using a definition of integrability taken from Chapter 13 of Spivak's Calculus:

> A function $f$ which is bounded on $[a,b]$ is **integrable** on $[a,b]$ if
> $$\sup\{L(f,P): P\text{ a partition of } [a,b]\} = \inf\{U(f,P) : P\text{ a partition of } [a,b]\}.$$
>
> In this case, this common number is called the **integral** of $f$ on [a,b] and is denoted by
> $$ \int_a ^b f.$$

**Edit:** I realize the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality for integrals immediately handles this problem. I was interested in trying to show a different route. In Calculus by Spivak, 3rd edition Chapter 13 problem 39(b) the second proof of Cauchy-Schwarz (not the quadratic one) uses $2xy \leq x^2 + y^2$ with
$$x = \frac{f(x)}{\sqrt{\int_a ^b f^2}}, y = \frac{g(x)}{\sqrt{\int_a ^b g^2}},$$
but fails to deal with the case where either denominator might be $0$. Here's a case where showing $\int_a ^b g^2 = 0 \implies \int_a ^b fg = 0$ is handy.

**Note:** I thought of a shorter proof, which I'll add to the end of this post. While this new proof is more direct, the original proof contains a few useful offshoots, namely, the lemma, and the proof that $\int g^2 = 0 \implies \int |g| = 0$.

**Original Proof**
I will make use of the following theorems:

**Theorem 1:** If $f$ and $g$ are each integrable on $[a,b]$ then their product $fg$ is integrable on $[a,b]$.

**Theorem 2:** If $f$ is integrable on $[a,b]$ and $f > 0$ on $[a,b]$, then $\int_a ^b f > 0$. (**Note** this theorem actually not needed. See bottom edit.)

**Theorem 3:** If $f$ is integrable on $[a,b]$ and $f \geq 0$ on $[a,b]$, then $\int_a ^b f \geq 0$.

**Theorem 4:** If $f$ is integrable on $[a,b]$ then $|f|$ is integrable on $[a,b]$.

**Theorem 5:** If $f$ is integrable on $[a,b]$, then
$$\left| \int_a ^b f \right| \leq \int_a ^b |f|.$$

We begin by proving the following Lemma:

**Lemma:** If $f$ and $g$ are each integrable on $[a,b]$, with $\int_a ^b g = 0$, and if $g\geq 0$ on $[a,b]$, then $\int_a ^b fg = 0$.

**Lemma Proof:**

From Theorem 1, we see that $\int_a ^b fg$ exists. Proof that the integral equals zero will be by given by contradiction. We begin by assuming $\int_a ^b fg > 0.$

**Case 1:** $\int_a ^b fg > 0$

If $\int_a ^b fg > 0$ then there must be some partition $P$ such that the lower sum $L(fg,P) > 0.$

This implies the existence of some subinterval $[t_{i-1}, t_i]$ on which the infimum of $fg$ is greater than $0$. (Otherwise, every lower sum would be $\leq 0$, and the integral could not be positive).

So, on this subinterval we have

\begin{align}
m_i &= \inf\{f(x)g(x)\text{: } t_{i-1} \leq x \leq t_i \}, \\
m_i &> 0,
\end{align}
and
$$f(x)g(x) \geq m_i > 0.$$

This tells that $f$ and $g$ are each nonzero on the subinterval. Furthermore, since $g$ is nonnegative by hypothesis, we see that both $f$ and $g$ must be positive.

But this implies (theorem 2) that the integral of $g$ over this subinterval:
$$\int_{t_{i-1}} ^{t_i} g > 0,$$
and *this* implies (because $\int g \geq 0$ everywhere else on $[a,b]$) $\int_a ^b g > 0$, which contradicts the hypothesis.

**Case 2:** $\int_a ^b fg < 0$

Here, we can apply the Case 1 arguments to the function $(-f)g$ to show

$$\int_a ^b fg < 0 \implies \int_a ^b (-f)g > 0 \implies \int_a ^b g > 0,$$

which again, is a contradiction.

**Lemma conclusion:**

Since we cannot have $\int_a ^b fg > 0$ or $< 0$, we must have $\int_a ^b fg = 0$.
$$\blacksquare$$

With the lemma in hand, we begin our proof. Many of the steps will be similar to those used in the lemma proof.

To restate the desired result, we wish to show:

**If $f$ and $g$ are each integrable on $[a,b]$, and $\int_a ^b g^2 = 0$, then $\int_a ^b fg = 0$.**

Since $g$ is integrable on $[a,b]$, theorem 4 tells us that $|g|$ is also integrable on $[a,b]$. Theorem 3 tells us that $\int_a ^b |g| \geq 0.$

Now, suppose $\int_a ^b |g| > 0$.

Similar to the lemma, this would mean there exists some partition $P$ such that the lower sum $L(|g|,P) > 0$. This would imply (like in the lemma) the existence of some subinterval $[t_{i-1}, t_i]$ on which the infimum of $|g|$ is greater than $0$.

So, on this subinterval we have

\begin{align}
m_i &= \inf\{|g(x)|\text{: } t_{i-1} \leq x \leq t_i \}, \\
m_i &> 0,
\end{align}
and

\begin{align}
|g(x)| &\geq m_i > 0, \\
g(x)^2 = |g(x)|^2 &\geq m_i ^2 > 0.\\
\end{align}

This, combined with Theorems 2 and 3 would imply that $\int_{t_{i-1}} ^{t_i} g^2 > 0$, and hence $\int_a ^b g^2 > 0$, contradicting the hypothesis.

Therefore, we must have  $\int_a ^b |g| = 0$.

We can now apply the lemma to the functions |f| and |g|, where |g| plays the role of $g$ in the lemma.

Since $|f|$ and $|g|$ are each integrable on $[a,b]$, with $\int_a ^b |g| = 0$, and $|g|\geq 0$ on $[a,b]$, we have
$$\int_a ^b |f||g| = 0.$$

Finally, applying theorem 5, we see
$$\left|\int_a ^b fg \right| \leq \int_a ^b |f||g| = 0,$$
$$0 \leq \left|\int_a ^b fg \right| \leq 0,$$
$$\int_a ^b fg = 0.$$
$$\blacksquare$$

Look mostly ok? Any glaring errors?

**Modified Original Proof without Theorem 2** I think we don't actually need Theorem 2.
Below are the relevant parts of the proof, revised to work without Theorem 2.

Lemma **Case 1:** $\int_a ^b fg > 0$

If $\int_a ^b fg > 0$ then there must be some partition $P$ such that the lower sum $L(fg,P) > 0.$

This implies the existence of some subinterval $[t_{i-1}, t_i]$ on which the infimum of $fg$ is greater than $0$. (Otherwise, every lower sum would be $\leq 0$, and the integral could not be positive).

So, on this subinterval we have

\begin{align}
m_i &= \inf\{f(x)g(x)\text{: } t_{i-1} \leq x \leq t_i \}, \\
m_i &> 0,
\end{align}
and
$$f(x)g(x) \geq m_i > 0.$$

This tells that $f$ and $g$ are each nonzero on the subinterval. Furthermore, since $g$ is nonnegative by hypothesis, we see that both $f$ and $g$ must be positive.

Since $f$ is bound on the subinterval there is some $M_{f,i}$ with
\begin{align}
M_{f,i} &= \sup\{f(x)\text{: } t_{i-1} \leq x \leq t_i \}, \\
M_{f,i} &> 0,
\end{align}
so
\begin{align}
M_{f,i}\cdot g(x) &\geq f(x)g(x) \geq m_i > 0, \\
g(x) &\geq \frac{m_i}{M_{f,i}} > 0.
\end{align}

Thus, $\frac{m_i}{M_{f,i}}$ is a lower bound for $g(x)$ on the subinterval. Since this lower bound is $> 0$, we must have $\inf\{g\} \cdot (t_i - t_{i-1}) > 0 \implies L(g,P) > 0 \implies \int_a ^b g > 0$, a contradiction.

We can apply a similar argument to dispense with the other later use of Theorem 2 in the main theorem proof. There, we show that $g(x)^2 \geq m_i ^2$ on the subinterval implies that $\inf\{g^2\} \geq m_i^2 > 0$, which in turn implies $\int_a^b g^2 > 0$.

**More Direct Approach**

Suppose $f$ and $g$ are each integrable on $[a,b]$.

Prove that if $\int_a ^b g^2 = 0$, then $\int_a ^b fg = 0$

**Proof**

From Theorem 1, we see that $\int_a ^b fg$ exists. Proof that the integral equals zero will be by given by contradiction. We begin by assuming $\int_a ^b fg > 0.$

**Case 1:** $\int_a ^b fg > 0$

If $\int_a ^b fg > 0$ then there must be some partition $P$ such that the lower sum $L(fg,P) > 0.$

This implies the existence of some subinterval $[t_{i-1}, t_i]$ on which the infimum of $fg$ is greater than $0$. (Otherwise, every lower sum would be $\leq 0$, and the integral could not be positive).

So, on this subinterval we have

\begin{align}
m_i &= \inf\{f(x)g(x)\text{: } t_{i-1} \leq x \leq t_i \}, \\
m_i &> 0,
\end{align}
and
$$f(x)g(x) \geq m_i > 0.$$

This tells that $f$ and $g$ are each nonzero on the subinterval.

But if this were the case, then $g^2$ would be $> 0$ on this same subinterval, which would mean $\int_a ^ b g^2 > 0$, a contradiction.

**Case 2:** $\int_a ^b fg < 0$

Here, we can apply the Case 1 arguments to $(-f)g$ to show

$$\int_a ^b fg < 0 \implies \int_a ^b (-f)g > 0 \implies (-f)g \neq 0 \text{ on } [t_{i-1}, t_i] \implies \int_a ^b g^2 > 0,$$

which again, is a contradiction. (Alternatively, we can make arguments identical to those in Case 1, but with upper sums/supremums swapped in for lower sums/infimums.)

**Proof conclusion:**

Since we cannot have $\int_a ^b fg > 0$ or $< 0$, we must have $\int_a ^b fg = 0$.
$$\blacksquare$$

Comment: Your proof is very clever and avoids any use of Lebesgue criterion. I hope this is hidden in theorem 2.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh I am confused by both the problem and your comment.  Please note that I am asking this question out of *ignorance*, and my only exposure to integration is Reimann integrals.  Doesn't the premise $\int_a^b g^2 = 0$ immediately imply that $g = 0$ throughout $(a,b)$, except at isolated points?  If so, why is this not immediately decisive?

Comment: @Paramanand Singh Theorem 2 comes out of a couple problems in Chapter 13 of Calculus by Spivak. The first shows that if $f$ is integrable on an interval, the points at which $f$ is continuous form a "dense set". The next combines this with an $f$ that is $> 0$ on the interval, to show $\int f > 0$. Of course, those problems are far cleverer than anything I've done here :)

Comment: @user2661923: yes. The points may not be isolated, though, and there could be uncountably many of them.

Comment: What type of integrability are your referring to? In any case, the solution to the problem s a one liner: If $\int^b_ag^2=0$ then $g^2=0$ almost surely in $[a.b]$ and so $fg=0$ almost surely. that is all!. If you are referring to Lebesgue integral, it is false that $f$ and $g$ integrable impies that $fg$ is integrable unless other conditions are added.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh: the whole premise is wrong!

Comment: @user2661923: no one is assuming that the functions are continuous. Otherwise the word "integrable" would not be needed. If you take a continuous function, and randomly replace countably many points with arbitrary values, the function is still Riemann integrable, with the same integral. You can even do uncountably many if you choose carefully.

Comment: @user2661923: I don't like silly games. Theorem 1 is false (unless you are talking about Riemann integrals, which is not clear for your text) Once you start with a false premise, sure you can prove whatever. If your goal is to show that $\int^b_ag^2$ implies $\int^b_afg=0$, then why torture the audience with abstract nonsense when the whole thing is actually very simple, as Martin mentioned in his answer.

Comment: @OliverDiaz I am confused.  Why is your comment addressed to me?  Isn't your comment consistent with the comment/question that I addressed to Paramanand Singh?

Comment: @OliverDiaz: I have interpreted the question in context of Riemann integrals and without the use of measure theory (including sets of measure zero, Lebesgue criterion etc). This should have been explicitly stated by asker.

Comment: @OliverDiaz: even then I admit the solution via Cauchy Schwarz is direct and far simpler. My initial reaction to the question was in terms of sets of measure zero and I saw that the solution offered in question avoided that.

Comment: I believe I recall an error in Spivak's proposed proof of Cauchy-Schwarz for integrals, where the cases aren't covered correctly. Whenever you have a polynomial $p(\lambda)=a\lambda^2+b\lambda+c$ such that for all $\lambda\in\Bbb{R}, p(\lambda)\geq 0$, it follows $b^2-4ac\leq 0$. This is true for ANY case.Why? because $p(\lambda)\geq 0$ implies $a\geq 0$ (if $a<0$ then it's a sad-faced quadratic so has to become negative). Now, if $a>0$, you can complete the square. If $a=0$, it says $b\lambda +c\geq 0$ for all $\lambda$, so again, $b=0$ (otherwise the straight line becomes negative).

Comment: Now, you can apply this reasoning to the inequality $0\leq \int_a^b(f-\lambda g)^2$, by expanding out the RHS. (at this point, I believe you should accept Martin's short answer, and realize that there's no circularity:)

Comment: This appears to be another instance where comments (excluding mine) contain a lot of interesting and important material

Comment: @peek-a-boo thank you, yes, I found that in the CS proof, the case of $\int g^2 = 0$ was do-able since, like you show, it implies $b$ is $0$. Later today though, thinking about things, I realized I could maybe prove this anyway and decided to try to give it a shot. I thought the result (and maybe moreso the lemma) were kinda useful, though I guess they're totally trivial if you know a little more math!

Comment: @ParamanandSingh I think Theorem 2 is actually not needed. See the edit at the bottom of the answer for details if at all interested.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This seems like a lot of work for something that is trivial to prove: right away you get that $g=0$ a.e., and so $fg=0$ a.e.

Even more direct, you can use Cauchy-Schwarz to immediately get (since $f$ is bounded so $f^2$ is bounded)
$$
\bigg|\int_a^b fg\bigg|\leq\bigg(\int_a^b g^2\bigg)^{1/2}\bigg(\int_a^b f^2\bigg)^{1/2}=0.
$$

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124124/discussion-on-answer-by-martin-argerami-if-int-a-b-g2-0-then-int-a-b).